# Tensorflow object detection API only evaluates the latest checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I've trained SSD mobilent v2 320x320 model with around 4k steps which produced quite a few checkpoints that are saved in my training folder.The issue I am experiencing now is that this only evaluates the latest checkpoint, but I'd like to evaluate all of them at once.

Ideally I would like to see the results in TensorBoard which shows the validation accuracy (mAP) of the different checkpoints as graph - which it does already, but just for the one checkpoint.

I have tried to run my evaluation code to generate a graph for my mAP but it shows my mAP with a simple dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each checkpoint refers to a previous state of your model during training. The graph you see on TensorBoard for mAP, at some points, is the same as the dots that are produced when you run the evaluation once on checkpoint because the checkpoints are not actually different models but your model at different times during training. So the graph of the last model is what you need.